# Simple, random encounters in a python text-adventure.. I´m stuck

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

i recently started simple coding with python 3 and i´m stuck with a simple problem:

---

```
import random

def enemy_bandit01():
     bandit01 = {'race': 'human', 'weapon': 'a sword'}

def enemy_orc01():
     orc01 = {'race': 'orc', 'weapon': 'a club'}

def enemy_wolf01():
     wolf01 = {'race': 'wolf', 'weapon': 'claws'}

encounter_choice = [enemy_bandit01, enemy_orc01, enemy_wolf01]

print('You fight against a ____. He has ____!')
```

---

I simply want python to pick a random enemy_x - function and then print out a text which includes the race/weapon etc.. without writing a new text for every enemy.

I am aware that this is a noob question, but i was not able to figure this out by myself.

Answer (score 2):

the dicts and your functions are really pointless as they are, they need to actual return something so you can randomly pick a pair:

```
from random import choice # use to pick a random element from  encounter_choice

def enemy_bandit01():
    return 'human', 'a sword' # just return a tuple


def enemy_orc01():
    return 'orc', 'a club'


def enemy_wolf01():
    return 'wolf', 'claws'


encounter_choice = [enemy_bandit01, enemy_orc01, enemy_wolf01]

# use str.format and unpack the tuple of race, weapon
print('You fight against a {}. He has {}!'.format(*choice(encounter_choice)()))
```

which may as well just become picking a random tuple from a list:

```
from random import choice

encounter_choice = [('human', 'a sword'), ( 'orc', 'a club'), ('wolf', 'claws') ]

print('You fight against a {}. He has {}!'.format(*choice(encounter_choice)))
```

`*choice(encounter_choice)` is equivalent to doing:

```
race, weapon = choice(encounter_choice)
print('You fight against a {}. He has {}!'.format(race, weapon))
```

Comment: Thanks, that really helped me out! :)